# getting java.io.FileNotFoundException for httpURLConnection

Tags: java, android

i am trying to implement simple login window but it is giving file not found exception....
i have searched lot on this but it is not running...

protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {

```
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String type=voids[0];

    String url="http://192.168.0.105/rootlogin.php";
    if(type.equals("initlogin")){
        try {
            String un=voids[1];
            String up=voids[2];
            URL u=new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection huc= (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            huc.setRequestMethod("POST");
            huc.setDoOutput(true);

            huc.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream os=huc.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
            String post_data= URLEncoder.encode("un","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(un,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("up","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(up,"UTF-8");
            bw.write(post_data);
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
            os.close();

            InputStream is=huc.getInputStream();
            //InputStream error = huc.getErrorStream();
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"ISO-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                result +=line;
            }

            br.close();
            is.close();
            huc.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you open that url in a browser? Do you get a 404 too? If not: Try to POST to that URL and see what happens.

Comment: it is showing message "Login unsuccessful"

Answer (score 0):

Odds are your php file is not located in the root directory of your server. Check the file path and correct the URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
 bw.close();
 os.close();
```

Remove those twice. Everywhere! It will close the socket too.

Comment: Yes. Those are for later. You have no connection now.